# Quote from Wittgenstein

Tags: history-of-philosophy, wittgenstein, quote

In his book *Il était sept fois la révolution*, Étienne Klein gives the following quotation of Ludwig Wittgenstein:

> Tout livre, même s'il est écrit avec une honnêteté totale, peut
>   toujours être tenu, d'un certain point de vue, comme sans valeur
>   aucune. Et ce, parce qu'en réalité nul n'a besoin d'écrire un livre,
>   étant donné qu'il y a bien d'autres choses à faire dans le monde.

Of course it's in French because the book is written in French. Here's my attempt at a translation in English:

> Any book, even if it is written with total honesty, may always be
>   regarded, from a certain point of view, as completely worthless. For in reality, no one needs to write a book, given that there are
>   many other things to do in the world.

Étienne Klein uses this quote by way of an epigraph, I found it very funny. But it is not sourced, and I couldn't find a trace of it upon a quick web search. Anyone knows where it is from? I can't imagine Klein just made it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the source is one of Wittgenstein's letters to [Ludwig von Ficker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_von_Ficker) (prospective publisher of the *Tractatus*): maybe that of December 4 or October 1919.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to check on the original edition, nor the English translation:

> *Briefe an Ludwig von Ficker*, Salzburg, 1969; English translation
>   “Letters to Ludwig von Ficker,” in C.G. Luckhardt (editor), [Wittgenstein: Sources and Perspectives](https://books.google.it/books?id=4N_BAAAACAAJ), Cornell University Press, 1979, pp. 82–98.

Comment: Dec.4 letter to von Ficker, that is right, but I am not sure where the French translation appears: a slightly different wording is found in the Revue Sud, hors serie 1986, p221.